# Materialize Init is disabling other Select dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Im facing an issue where I am using Materialize and am dynamically adding new Select menus to my page. When I initialize the first set of Selects, they work fine. If I add a second set and initialize that same set, the previous one stops working. I have been trying to solve this issue for a few hours and I am not sure where my error is.

The form is where the Select menus will be added.
When I add the first set of selects, it works properly. If I add the second set, the first one stops working and I am not sure why.

```js
function addMesocycle() {
    var form = document.querySelector("#mesocycleForm");
    var name = "Mesocycle " + mesocycleIndex;

    var content = 
    `
        <p>${name}</p>
        <label style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46);">Fase:</label>
        <select id="${"fase" + mesocycleIndex}">
            <option value='Option1' selected>Option1</option>
            <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
            <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
            <option value='Option4'>Option4</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46);">Período:</label>
        <select id="${"period" + mesocycleIndex}">
            <option value='Option1'>Option1</option>
            <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
            <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
            <option value='Option4'>Option4</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    `;

    form.innerHTML += content;

    var faseID = "#fase" + mesocycleIndex;
    var periodID = "#period" + mesocycleIndex;

    var ids = [faseID, periodID];

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(ids);
    M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    
    mesocycleIndex++;
}
```

```html
<form id="mesocycleForm"></form>
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/JoaoBM/pen/MWJdLEB

Im not sure what is causing the previous Selects to be disabled. If you could help me, Id be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for anyone curious in the future.

I posted this issue on Materialize's Github Issues and was told to

"avoid using `innerHTML`, because the internal state of the select elements will be lost. Instead of using `innerHTML`, you can use `insertAdjacentHTML`. For example :

```
form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);
```

IMO, this is not the bug from materializecss."

You can find the Github Issue here: https://github.com/materializecss/materialize/issues/124

Here is the final block of code, using pieces of @ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ's answer (so it can be more tidy):

```js
var mesocycleIndex = 1;

function addMesocycle() {
  var form = document.querySelector("#mesocycleForm");
  var name = "Mesocycle " + mesocycleIndex;

  var content =
    `
      <p>${name}</p>
      
      <label style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46);">Fase:</label>
      <select id="fase${mesocycleIndex}" class="fase">
        <option value='Option1'>Option1</option>
        <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
        <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
        <option value='Option4'>Option4</option>
      </select>

      <br>

      <label style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46);">Período:</label>
      <select id="period${mesocycleIndex}" class="period">
        <option value='Option1'>Option1</option>
        <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
        <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
        <option value='Option4'>Option4</option>
      </select>

      <br>
    `;

  form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);

  var ids = ['.fase', '.period'];

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(ids);

  M.FormSelect.init(elems);

  mesocycleIndex++;
}
```

Which you can see working here: https://codepen.io/JoaoBM/pen/RwpbXRZ

Hope this helps someone in the future with the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="mesocycleForm"></form>
    <button onClick="addMesocycle()">Add</button>
</body>
<script>
    var mesocycleIndex = 1;

    function addMesocycle() {
        var form = document.querySelector("#mesocycleForm");
        var name = "Mesocycle " + mesocycleIndex;
        var content =
            `
        <p>${name}</p>
        <label style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46);">Fase:</label>
        <select id="fase${mesocycleIndex}" class="face">
            <option value='Option1' selected>Option1</option>
            <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
            <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
            <option value='Option4'>Option4</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46);">Período:</label>
        <select id="period${mesocycleIndex}" class="period">
            <option value='Option1'>Option1</option>
            <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
            <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
            <option value='Option4'>Option4</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    `;

        form.innerHTML += content;
        // var faseID = "#fase" + mesocycleIndex;
        // var periodID = "#period" + mesocycleIndex;
        // var ids = [faseID, periodID];
        var ids = ['.face', '.period'];
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll(ids);

        M.FormSelect.init(elems);
        mesocycleIndex++;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I dont't know what "M.FormSelect.init(elems)" realy do. But it initialize... so give it as parameter all elements with class .face and .period  .... and works.

Comment: Yes but notice that when you add 2 sets, the first stops working.You cannot use the first set of selects. Only the 2nd. That's my issue